# Symfony - pass GET parameters to another route?

Tags: csv, symfony, filter, parameters, get

I have a table with filters, and i want to download the rows as csv, filtered.

My function to get filters from form:

```
public function getFilters($request)
{
    $filters = [
        'stato' => $request->get('stato'),
        'cliente' => $request->get('cliente'),
        'registrar' => $request->get('registrar'),
        'creazione_inizio' => $request->get('creazione_inizio'),
        'creazione_fine' => $request->get('creazione_fine'),
        'scadenza_inizio' => $request->get('scadenza_inizio'),
        'scadenza_fine' => $request->get('scadenza_fine'),
        'scadenza_pagamento_inizio' => $request->get('scadenza_pagamento_inizio'),
        'scadenza_pagamento_fine' => $request->get('scadenza_pagamento_fine'),
    ];

    return $filters;
}
```

On the page where the table is i have this code and it works fine:

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard", name="dashboard")
 */
public function dashboard(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator): Response
{
    $filters = $this->getFilters($request);
}
```

But on the route to export csv i have this and $filters is always null:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/report/report.csv", name="domains_data_csv")
 */
public function exportDomainsDataCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $filters = $this->getFilters($request);
}
```

I have the filters form and the button to download csv on the dashboard page.
Any tips to make it work?

*EDIT*

My dashboard page is made like this:

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <span class="h2">Dashboard</span>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    {{ include('Admin/includes/_search.html.twig') }}
</div>
{{ include('Admin/includes/_filter.html.twig') }}
{% if domains %}
    <div class="col-auto">
        <a href="{{ path('domains_data_csv') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Scarica CSV</a>
    </div>
    {{ include('Admin/includes/_domains_table.html.twig',{ 'domains':domains }) }}

    {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" aria-current="page" href="{{path('new_domain')}}" role="button">Nuovo dominio</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Filters form:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <a class="text-decoration-none text-reset" id="filter-header" href="#collapseExample" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center">
            <h5 class="pe-3">Filtri</h5>
            <div class="border-1 bg-success border border-success w-100" style="opacity:unset;"></div>
            <i class="bi bi-chevron-right ps-3 fs-3 text-success arrow"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form id="form-filter-status" method="GET">
            {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                <div class="row mb-3 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="card col-sm-3 mx-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title">Stato:</div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <select name="stato" class="form-select" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
                                    <option value="" {% if filters.stato is empty %} selected {% endif %}>Seleziona...</option>
                                    <option value="1" {% if filters.stato == 1 %} selected {% endif %}>Attivo</option>
                                    <option value="2" {% if filters.stato == 2 %} selected {% endif %}>Richiesta Dismissione</option>
                                    <option value="3" {% if filters.stato == 3 %} selected {% endif %}>Dismesso</option>
                                    <option value="4" {% if filters.stato == 4 %} selected {% endif %}>Richiesto Trasferimento</option>
                                    <option value="5" {% if filters.stato == 5 %} selected {% endif %}>Trasferito</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card col-sm-3 mx-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title">Cliente:</div>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <select name="cliente" class="form-select" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
                                    <option value="" {% if filters.cliente is empty %} selected {% endif %}>Seleziona...</option>
                                    <option value="1" {% if filters.cliente == 1 %} selected {% endif %}>KINETIKON s.r.l.</option>
                                    <option value="2" {% if filters.cliente == 2 %} selected {% endif %}>CINQUEBIT s.r.l.</option>
                                    <option value="3" {% if filters.cliente == 3 %} selected {% endif %}>JAKALA S.p.A.</option>
                                    <option value="4" {% if filters.cliente == 4 %} selected {% endif %}>IN.SI. s.r.l.</option>
                                    <option value="5" {% if filters.cliente == 5 %} selected {% endif %}>PAGNOSSIN s.r.l.</option>
                                    <option value="6" {% if filters.cliente == 6 %} selected {% endif %}>ELEPHASE s.r.l.</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card col-sm-3 mx-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title">Register:</div>

                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <select name="registrar" class="form-select" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
                                    <option value="" {% if filters.registrar is empty %} selected {% endif %}>Seleziona...</option>
                                    <option value="1" {% if filters.registrar == 1 %} selected {% endif %}>Register</option>
                                    <option value="2" {% if filters.registrar == 2 %} selected {% endif %}>OpenProvider</option>
                                    <option value="3" {% if filters.registrar == 3 %} selected {% endif %}>TowerTech</option>
                                    <option value="4" {% if filters.registrar == 4 %} selected {% endif %}>Aruba</option>
                                    <option value="5" {% if filters.registrar == 5 %} selected {% endif %}>Aruba Business</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="card col-sm-3 mx-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">Creazione</div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text col-2" id="creazione_inizio">Da:</span>
                            <input type="date" name="creazione_inizio" class="form-control" value="{{filters.creazione_inizio}}" placeholder="Creazione inizio" aria-label="Creazione inizio" aria-describedby="creazione_inizio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text col-2" id="creazione_fine">A:</span>
                            <input type="date" name="creazione_fine" class="form-control" value="{{filters.creazione_fine}}" placeholder="Creazione fine" aria-label="Creazione fine" aria-describedby="creazione_fine">
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Filtra data creazione</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card col-sm-3 mx-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">Scadenza</div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text col-2" id="scadenza_inizio">Da:</span>
                            <input type="date" name="scadenza_inizio" class="form-control" value="{{filters.scadenza_inizio}}" placeholder="Scadenza inizio" aria-label="Scadenza inizio" aria-describedby="scadenza_inizio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text col-2" id="scadenza_fine">A:</span>
                            <input type="date" name="scadenza_fine" class="form-control" value="{{filters.scadenza_fine}}" placeholder="Scadenza fine" aria-label="Scadenza fine" aria-describedby="scadenza_fine">
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Filtra data scadenza</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card col-sm-3 mx-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-title">Scadenza pagamento</div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text col-2" id="scadenza_pagamento_inizio">Da:</span>
                            <input type="date" name="scadenza_pagamento_inizio" class="form-control" value="{{filters.scadenza_pagamento_inizio}}" placeholder="Scadenza pagamento inizio" aria-label="Scadenza pagamento inizio" aria-describedby="scadenza_pagamento_inizio">
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <span class="input-group-text col-2" id="scadenza_pagamento_fine">Da:</span>
                            <input type="date" name="scadenza_pagamento_fine" class="form-control" value="{{filters.scadenza_pagamento_fine}}" placeholder="Scadenza pagamento fine" aria-label="Scadenza pagamento fine" aria-describedby="scadenza_pagamento_fine">
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Filtra data scadenza pagamento</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            {% if query is defined %}
                <input type="hidden" name="query" value="{{query}}">
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should pass those filters to your `domains_data_csv` route the same way you do with the other route.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @StephanVierkant -> I pass the filters the same way, with "$filters = $this->getFilters($request);" but $filters is always NULL

Comment: it's how you pass the filters from the frontend that matters

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? `getFilters` does not return `NULL` in the given code

Comment: Show the code for "filters form and the button to download csv"

Comment: @NicoHaase the thing is that when i press the button to download as CSV (route "domains_data_csv") the url is always like this: /report/report.csv
without get parameters. Otherway when i filter on the dashboard page the url change with get parameters and the filters works well.
i edited the post with the dashboard page twig

Comment: @NicoHaase i think i only need to create the {{ path('domains_data_csv') }} with the get parameters from the filters form, but i don't know/find how to

Comment: What do you mean by "i don't know/find how to"? If you write the path like that, it's obvious that it does not receive any parameters. Why not add the filters to the route in the controller, and pass the generated route to the template in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the current `GET` parameters (from URL, not form) You should be able to modify the `href` as follows:

```
<a href="{{ path('domains_data_csv') ~ "?" ~ app.request.queryString }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Scarica CSV</a>
```

To use the current form values you need to use JavaScript to set the form's `action` attribute value to that returned by `{{ path('domains_data_csv') }}` and submit the form.

Comment: It worked! with {{ path('domains_data_csv') ~ "?" ~ app.request.queryString }}

Thank you so much!!